# C# - Setup project generates .exe that always triggers UAC

Tags: c#, user-permissions

im creating an WindowsForm app that install some stuff and executes some php scripts. Then, I created a setup project in order to install the app and its requisites. The problem is that the app always asks for admin permission when executing the app. I even just re-coded the app to simply show a Windows Dialog box. Installed it again and keep getting the uac prompt when executing the app.

Is it possible to run the app without admin permission? Already tried manifest.

Comment: Could you provide an example for us to try?

Comment: The amount of code isn't small, im just trying to find if there is something causing the setup project to build the app with admin rights, but still found nothing